# How i can display in the format properly(SQL plus)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

[image]

Anyone can help ??
And why the customer value(Ah Seng) cannot insert?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Erm...why?
Sorry,i am still new =-=

Comment: Because it makes it annoying to read and makes it hard to find the question in the future.

Comment: Also, some of us don't have access to see the pictures, due to firewall restrictions. And, if you paste in text, that allows us (should it be necessary) to copy it directly from your post, rather than having to type it all out again.

Comment: Sorry,now i know it....
Thanks for notice~

Answer (score 0):

To fix the display, use the SQL Plus command COLUMN  FORMAT <...>

For example:

```
column cust_name format a20
column email format a20
```

Experiment with the width of the columns till everything fits on one line.

For the email that is rejected: see what the check constraint is. Perhaps it doesn't allow the "local" part of the address (before the "at" sign) to be all digits.